# Command Prompt is not working properly

Tags: command-prompt

I want to go from `C` drive to `E:\Installation Drive\Derby\db-derby-10.9.1.0-bin\bin`"using command prompt but I am not able to do this. Can anyone give me the solution? I tried following lines of code:

Microsoft Windows [Version 6.0.6002]
Copyright (c) 2006 Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

```
C:\Users\Gaurav>cd/

C:\>cd E:

E:\

C:\>cd E:\Installation Drive\Derby\db-derby-10.9.1.0-bin\bin

C:\>cd E:

E:\Installation Drive\Derby\db-derby-10.9.1.0-bin\bin

C:\>cd E:

E:\Installation Drive\Derby\db-derby-10.9.1.0-bin\bin

C:\>
```

Comment: use `E:\ ` to change your directory to `E` drive first, then `E:>cd E:\Installation Drive\Derby\db-derby-10.9.1.0-bin\bin`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
cd /d E:\Installation Drive\Derby\db-derby-10.9.1.0-bin\bin
```

would probably be the easiest way...

Answer (score 1):

Try typing `E:` to change drive then `cd "Installation Drive\Derby\db-derby-10.9.1.0-bin\bin"` to change directory.

Answer (score 0):

Try to type like this
To change the drive `E:`
then to go to folder use `cd` and then past the location.

like

```
E: cd Installation Drive\Derby\db-derby-10.9.1.0-bin\bin
```

and press enter button. Hope this will help